# What is the sum of the series SQRT ($1 - x^2 - x^4 - x^6 - x^8...) $?

Tags: sequences-and-series

What is the sum of the following series?

$\sqrt{1 - x^2 - x^4 - x^6 - x^8...}$

Thank You.

Comment: You can write the argument of the square root as $$2-\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}x^{2n}$$and the sum is a geometric series.

Answer (score 0):

COMMENT.- For $|x|\lt1$ you have
$$1-x^2(1+x^2+x^3+\cdots+x^n+\cdots)$$ Hence the sum is $$1+\frac{x^2}{1-x}$$ For other values the series diverges to $-\infty$.